# Where does ASP.NET virtual path resolve the tilde "~"?

Tags: asp.net

Where does ASP.NET virtual path resolve the tilde `~` in the links, for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Css/Site.css" />
```

Does it redirect, or `RedirectToAction` in ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. Perhaps you need to re-format it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It gets it from here:

```
VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(contentPath, httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
```

Here is the reflector output for `PathHelpers` class in **System.Web.Mvc DLL**:

```
private static string GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, string contentPath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentPath))
    {
        return contentPath;
    }
    if (contentPath[0] == '~')
    {
        string virtualPath = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(contentPath, httpContext.Request.ApplicationPath);
        string str2 = httpContext.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier(virtualPath);
        return GenerateClientUrlInternal(httpContext, str2);
    }
    NameValueCollection serverVariables = httpContext.Request.ServerVariables;
    if ((serverVariables == null) || (serverVariables["HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_URL"] == null))
    {
        return contentPath;
    }
    string relativePath = MakeRelative(httpContext.Request.Path, contentPath);
    return MakeAbsolute(httpContext.Request.RawUrl, relativePath);
}
```

Comment: my question is based on this problem "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563043/root-path-with-tilde-does-not-change-upper-case-to-lower-case" to see the link "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.aspx ", I think the problem is not in asp.net-mvc, but in IIS. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

See [MSDN:Web Project Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

> ASP.NET includes the Web application
>   root operator (~), which you can use
>   when specifying a path in server
>   controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~
>   operator to the root of the current
>   application. You can use the ~
>   operator in conjunction with folders
>   to specify a path that is based on the
>   current root.

Basically, the purpose of the tilde is so that you can have a path that resolves properly even if you deploy your website to different places.  Relative paths cannot accomplish this easily because controls may be rendered in different folders within your website.  Absolute paths cannot accomplish this because your website may be deployed to different locations -- if nothing else, this is the case for test deployments made locally vs release deployments to the live server.

`Server.MapPath` can be used for similar reasons.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net translates the tilde(~) with the application's root directory in every *runat=server* control. It is the equivalent for the [HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.appdomainappvirtualpath%28VS.90%29.aspx) Property.

Comment: No, it is not equivalent. AppDomainAppVirtualPath is "The virtual path of the directory that contains the application hosted in the current application domain" (virtual directory). It is certainly not the same with application's root directory, at least from IIS7.