# NullReferenceException when calling UrlHelper.Content(string) in a unit test

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I have a few `UrlHelper` extension methods that I'd like to unit test.  However, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` from the `UrlHelper.Content(string)` method when the path begins with "~/".  Anyone know what the issue is?

```
[Test]
public void DummyTest()
{
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext(context.Object, new RouteData());
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(requestContext);

    string path = urlHelper.Content("~/test.png");

    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(path);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the UrlHelper.Content() method?

Comment: seems like simple "file not found" in the relative to the assembly path.

Comment: @MikeParkhill The UrlHelper.Content method is defined in the System.Web.Mvc namespace.  That's not one of my methods.

Comment: @trailmax That's not how `UrlHelper.Content` works.  It converts a path like '~/test.png' into a path suitable to be rendered in an anchor or image tag.

Comment: @devlife, of course, you're right! (smacks forehead)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you create the UrlHelper with the RouteContext the HttpContext is null in your unit test environment.  Without it you'll hit a lot of NullReferenceExceptions when you try to call any methods that rely on it.

There are a number of threads out there on mocking the various web contexts.  You can check out this one:
[How do I mock the HttpContext in ASP.NET MVC using Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452418/how-do-i-mock-the-httpcontext-in-asp-net-mvc-using-moq)

or this one
[Mock HttpContext.Current in Test Init Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method)

**EDIT:**
The following will work.  Note you need to mock the HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath and the HttpContext.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier().

```
[Test]
public void DummyTest() {
    var context = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    context.Setup( c => c.Request.ApplicationPath ).Returns( "/tmp/testpath" );
    context.Setup( c => c.Response.ApplyAppPathModifier( It.IsAny<string>( ) ) ).Returns( "/mynewVirtualPath/" );
    RequestContext requestContext = new RequestContext( context.Object, new RouteData() );
    UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper( requestContext );

    string path = urlHelper.Content( "~/test.png" );

    Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty( path );
}
```

I found the details for this in the following thread:
[Where does ASP.NET virtual path resolve the tilde "~"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563235/where-does-asp-net-virtual-path-to-resolving-the-tilde)

Comment: I tried the suggestions from those links to no avail.  It might be worth pointing out that the test passes if you remove the "~" from the path.

Comment: From the MSDN article: "If the specified content path does not start with the tilde (~) character, this method returns contentPath unchanged."  So, if you take the tilde out it's not doing any actual work under the hood.