# Javascript and CSS files don't work when using a sub-directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to get the base path because currently my application is hosted as a sub-site like:

```
www.example.com/site1/site2/
```

Where my IIS application is setup in site2, but my razor pages and master page is referencing things like:

```
 <link href="/Assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

When in this case it should be like:

```
 <link href="/site1/site2/Assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I also have images like:

```
 <img src="/Assets/images/logo.jpg" />
```

How can I get this to work in a dynamic way so I don't have to hard code the sub-directory somewhere?

Comment: `@Url.Content("~/path/to/file.js")` ?

Comment: Notice the tilde ~ at the front of the path.  It's important.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563235/where-does-asp-net-virtual-path-to-resolving-the-tilde

Answer (score 5):

You should use the built in helpers to get the relative path to your content.

```
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Assets/css/styles.css")" rel="stylesheet">
```

For a site hosted at `www.domain.com/site/subdirectory`, the above will render out to

```
<link href="/site/subdirectory/Assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

And, if you ever move your site or change your root path, you will not have to change your markup code.

More examples:

**Images**

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/images/logo.jpg")" />
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/Scripts/jsfile.js")"></script>
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by link URLs?

Comment: This method is for providing the correct path to any static content on your web server.  If you are asking about how to make links to controller/actions -> that is a different issue.  But one we can help you with.

Comment: Yes for links, so the @Action.ActionLink have to be aware of the sub-directories etc.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink() references a controller/action and has nothing to do with subDirectories.  When you put @Html.ActionLink("Text", "action", "controller") it has no bearing on what level of a subdirectory your application is at.