# Relative Path tilde (~) not working in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, relative-path, razor-2

When I run my project on my machine, it runs on `http://localhost:53998/` but when I deploy it to `http://test.myserver.com/MyApp/` all links break. I'm using the relative path tilde (`~`), so a navigation link would be something like:

```
<a href="~/SomeCtrl/Index">Some Action</a>
```

On localhost, this works fine (when root is `/`), but when I deploy my project under `/MyApp/` it links the action to `http://test.myserver.com/SomeCtrl/Index` instead of `http://test.myserver.com/MyApp/SomeCtrl/Index` so I always get a 404.

Isn't this what the tilde (`~`) should take care of? Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT:**

This works correctly:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Some Action", "Index", "SomeCtrl")
```

And this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SomeCtrl")">Some Action</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried using `@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")`? e.g. `@Url.Action("Index", "SomeCtrl")`

Comment: You can also use the `@Html.ActionLink()` extension method with the same parameters (plus the 'link text') which will produce the HTML for the link for you

Comment: Both `@Url.Action` and `@Html.ActionLink` work correctly, but what I would like to know is why the tilda (`~`) doesn't work?

Comment: No idea, but there may be a clue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563235/where-does-asp-net-virtual-path-to-resolving-the-tilde - looks like it uses `Request.ApplicationPath` - maybe it's picking up the wrong path - or maybe you have defined your application a level higher in IIS than the site root you want

Comment: Makes no sense. ~ and @Html.ActionLink and @Url.Action should all use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath` which would be `/MyApp/`

Comment: I don't see that in the code on the linked SO question - they must be doing something different or you wouldn't get an issue.

Comment: I'll keep this question open because this is an odd behavior.

Comment: You cannot use the tilda in the anything but code that is processed by the framework. As you have seen "<a href="~/SomeCtrl/Index">Some Action</a>" does not work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077558/use-of-tilde-in-asp-net-path

Comment: @KenBrittain That's not true, MVC4 and above will process `~` correctly into relative urls. The question you link to is from before that time.

Comment: Make sure you're using Razor 2 and not Razor 1

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, the answer in my case was I had some URL Rewrite settings which were changing the tilde path to point to a different folder. I had to sort out these rewrite rules and it fixed my problem.