# Relative paths are not working when I publish MVC 5 website?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC5 Project, I have used Jquery and to use Controller Actions, I used relative path. Here is a sample:-

```
 $("#divTree").jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                "url": "/Customer/GetList",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "check_callback": true
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "json_data"]
    });
```

I am also using relative paths in jquery.ajax() method. All relative paths are working in visual studio. But when I publish and host it in IIS, relative paths are not working.

In my asp.net web forms projects I am either using ReloveUrl() or ~.

How should i handle it in MVC 5 project.?

Comment: use (~) in the url  "url": "~/Customer/GetList"

Comment: (~) does not work in MVC 5 project.

Comment: It is working since MVC 4. check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22452518/relative-path-tilde-not-working-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @ala: I guess the link you shared says (~) is not working

Comment: check this link http://beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider not hard coding the URLs in MVC apps and using the provided helpers instead. If the script is within a view, you can use @Url.Action() to generate the URL. If not, you can still pass it in as a param to the JS in some way or another.

```
$("#divTree").jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            "url": '@Url.Action("Customer", "GetList")',
            "dataType": "json"
        },
        "check_callback": true
    },
    "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "json_data"]
});
```

Comment: Yes, most likely just by wrapping it with a function and passing it in

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$("#divTree").jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                "url": "~/Customer/GetList",
                "dataType": "json"
            },
            "check_callback": true
        },
        "plugins": ["contextmenu", "dnd", "json_data"]
    });
```