# Override what the tilde (~) resolves to in a razor view page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, razor

I wanting to know if at all possible, if can I override what the tilde (~) resolves to in a razor view page.

For example

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css">
```

Is there somewhere that I can override what the tilde resolves too? I have a custom view engine and base view page but cant seem to find it!

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I have content e.g. css and images stored with seperate folders for modules. The views that are being rendered belong to a module so I would like ~ to resolve to the modules content folder rather than the host.

I already know the paths for my modules etc, I just want to be able to change the **~** from resolving to **/**, to resolve to **/Modules/ModuleName/**.

Comment: What do you want to override it to? `~` means the "application root".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563235/where-does-asp-net-virtual-path-resolve-the-tilde?rq=1

Comment: I have content e.g. css and images stored with seperate folders for modules. The views that are being rendered belong to a module so I would like ~ to resolve to the modules content folder rather than the host.

Comment: Can you post an example, like a simple folder tree of what you have?

Comment: If you already know the path to the module, why not use `~/ModulePath/ResourseInside`? So in your case, `~/Modules/ModuleName/...`.

Comment: The views are held inside the module, so I would find it neater to just write ~/Content/.., I've already sorted the @Url.Content and other similar methods.