# Image not displayed with html helper returning a relative image path but displays when the same path is hard-coded in the view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, image

I have the following code in my view:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
                    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageCaption)</p>
                        </div>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageFilePath)" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

`@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageFilePath)` returns a relative image path that is stored in a database in the following format:  "~/Content/userProfiles/profile01/image.JPG".
 When my view is rendered, my image appears to have a broken link (it is not displayed). However, when I hard-code the path in the image source it displays as required. Stated differently, `<img class="img-responsive" src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageFilePath)" alt="">` returns a broken link where `<img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/userProfiles/profile01/image.JPG" alt="">` displays the image. 
**Why isn't my image displayed using the html helper even though it returns a path that works when hard-coded into the view?**  .

Comment: Hmmm... interesting, just out of curiousity could you try to use `@Url.Content`, something like this `<img class="img-responsive" src="@Url.Content(Model.ImageFilePath)" alt="">` and see if that helps?

Comment: Can you check generated HTML source after you use Html.DisplayFor ?
isn't it renders <label> tag in src?

Comment: can you say this string stored in your database with quotes? If so that could be the issue

Comment: @Michael, It throws an error. @K D, the generated source is `<img class="img-responsive" src="~/Content/userProfiles/sisokhuz@gmail.com/ZIMG_0825.JPG" alt="" style="">`. @teo van kot, the path is saved without the quotes. Instead of locating the image, it displays the path.

Comment: And what happends when you delte tilda at the begining of your path from db? `/Content/userProfiles/sisokhuz@gmail.com/ZIMG_0825.JPG`

Comment: @teovankot Ahh, that appears to have fixed my problem. Thanks. How do I flag or vote this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete tilda (`~`) from the begining of your path in db.

I mean change this:

> ~/Content/userProfiles/sisokhuz@gmail.com/ZIMG_0825.JPG

To This:

> /Content/userProfiles/sisokhuz@gmail.com/ZIMG_0825.JPG

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain to me why the tilda didn't work. Or when I should and should not use it.

Comment: @Bonga [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4563235/1849444) is answer why it resolve static paths on page. But when you get path from model property `VirtualPathUtility` just don't be called.